# Line through a a given point in the first quadrant of the coordinate plane to form a triangle

Tags: geometry

Consider a straight line with negative gradient passing through the positive quadrant (where all co-ordinates are positive, or the first quadrant) of the co-ordinate plane and intercepting the $x$ and $y$ axes to form a triangle with them.

Which points in the positive quadrant can the line pass through such that the triangle always has area $2$?

I've considered the point $(1,1)$ and formed an equation in terms of the rectangle made by the point and the two triangles either side of it. My hypothesis is that anything right of $(1,1)$ doesn't work

Comment: hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited in a little

Comment: any points (0,2x) and (x,0)

Comment: A line going through $(1,1)$ and intersecting both the $x$ and $y$ axis in the first quadrant will have points on the right of $(1,1)$ (the point will just have lower $y$ coordinates)

Answer (score 2):

Guide:

Suppose the gradient is $m$ and the $x$-intercept is $x$, then the $y$ intercept is $-mx$.

That is we want to have $$\frac12\cdot x\cdot (-mx) = 2$$

Hence solving for $x$ in terms of $m$ should fully determine the line.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line in the plane, with slope $-m$ can be written as $$y=-mx+b$$To get the condition to have the area $2$, we need to calculate the intersection with the axes. If $x=0$, you get $y=b$. If $y=0$, you get $$x=\frac bm$$
The area of the triangle is then $$2=\frac 12 b\frac bm$$which yields $$b=2\sqrt m$$
Going back to the original equation $$y=-mx+2\sqrt m$$
Now let's suppose that I have a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on such line. What would happen if I keep $x_0$ constant, and I want to either increase or decrease $y_0$? Can I find a different $m$? Otherwise saying, given $x_0$, for what values of $y_0$ can I find a solution for the following equation: $$y_0=-mx_0+2\sqrt m$$We can write this as a quadratic equation in $X=\sqrt m$
$$x_0X^2-2X+y_0=0$$
To have a real solution, we need the discriminant to be positive, so $$1-x_0y_0\ge 0$$ or $$x_0y_0\le 1$$
What it means that any point that lies in the first quadrant below the hyperbola $xy=1$ is part of at least one line such that the intersections with the axis form a triangle with area $2$.